Is it possible for a function to have a range that is not a set?
I was curious about functions that are not well defined such that the only issue causing the function to not be well defined is that at least one of its inputs  is not within the codomain. For example $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ with $f(x)=cos(x)$ has unique outputs i.e $\forall a,b$ $\,$ $a=b \Rightarrow f(a)=f(b)$ but it is not well-defined since values like $cos(\pi) \not\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ but if we extended $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{+} \cup f[\mathbb{R}]$ $\;$ $\;$  (note that $ f[\mathbb{R}] =$ {${f(a) : a \in \mathbb{R}}$} ) then $f$ can be well-defined by extension of codomain becoming $f_e : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+} \cup f[\mathbb{R}]$.
My initial question was does there exist a function $f:A \rightarrow B$ that has unique and defined outputs such that $f[A] \not \subseteq B$ and there doesn't exist a set k such that $k \cup B \subseteq f[A] $. Now if $f[A]$ was a set then the solution is easy set $k=f[A]$, so my question then shifted to the idea does there exist a function such that $f[A]$ is not a set in ZFC, since if $f[A]$ is not a set then there exists no codomain to make f a well-defined function (since the codomain is a set).
Then I thought if A is a well ordered infinite set we can defined $f$ as $f(x_i)$={$f(x_{i+1})$} with $x_{i+1}$ being the next element after $x_i$ in the woset. Notice that $f(x_0)$ = {{...{$f(x_n)$}...}} which has $n$ pairs of set brackets which I'll denote as $f(x_0)$=$^n${$f(x_n)$}$^n$. Furthermore $f[A]$={$f(x_0)$,$f(x_1)$, $f(x_2)$...} and hence we should obtain a set $^{\infty}${$f(x_{\infty})$}$^{\infty}$ $\in f[A]$ but $^{\infty}${$f(x_{\infty})$}$^{\infty}$ implies that $f(x_{\infty})$={$f(x_{\infty})$} but in ZFC A={A} is not a set nor defined and hence $f[A]$ which contains collection in the form A={A} is not a set either in ZFC.
My questions are when defining a function $f:A \rightarrow B$ that has possible outputs outside of $B$ does $f[A]$ have to be a set. Secondly is $^{\infty}${$f(x_{\infty})$}$^{\infty}$ obtainable from the set $f[A]$ (i.e it that infnitly nested set within $f[A]$  ) and if that set if obtainable from $f[A]$ wouldn't that make it an output of $f$ which would make $f$ not defined for any input since $f(x_0)$=$^{\infty}${$f(x_{\infty})$}$^{\infty}$ which implies $\forall i$ $f(x_i)$ = $^{\infty}${$f(x_{\infty})$}$^{\infty}$.

You're looking for the axiom schema of replacement.

Thanks! @SassatelliGiulio
